# Selenium PHP Unit How to wait for filtering actions in a grid

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, wait

I have a grid with  an filtering option.
Whenever I sendKeys to the filtering field, it will start searching

I'm using Selenium: facebook webdriver with phpunit.

```
$this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="datatable_classrooms_wrapper"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tfoot/tr/td[1]/div/input'))->click();  
$var = "Selenium";
for ($i = 0; $i<strlen($var); $i++) {$character = \substr($var, $i,1);
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys($character);
}
// Here it searches for the item $character in the grid
// More actions as followed, but how do I wait here until the searches are done?
```

Here I will search for Selenium in the grid but how do I wait until it's done filtering?
Sometimes it can take up to 12 seconds before it filters.

I guess I  could just put a `sleep(15);` in it but if it happens to be longer then 15 seconds it won't work.
Also `implicit wait` and `explicit wait` won't do the trick here  , since sending the keys goes as normal as it can get.

Any suggestions towards how I can do this?

HTML:

```
<td class="dataTables_filter text-left" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 277px;"> 
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" value="" data-position="1" data-type="text" class="form-control input-sm"></div></td>
```

Comment: It's very strange that webdriver takes 12 second to find element. Attach sample html please. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreyEgorov You understood wrong, when it finds the element and enters the text, it takes mostly btw 8-12 seconds before it starts searching for an the item. Since there is a lot of data in it. It doesn't take 12sec to find the element. The issue is that I don't know how to wait for the filtering to happen and I don't know how long it will take before the filtering is compleet.

Comment: ok, sorry, little misunderstanding

Comment: No problem, but any idea's perhaps? ;P You seem to knew a lot of it(selenium) in other posts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you need somehow wait untill search will be finished, here is my sugesstions:

1. Do you have loading animarion while search appears? If yes, it will help you. You can set explicit wait until this loadin animation will dissappear, then the search will completed
2. Possible results appears somewhere (e.g. in table, i don't know). So you can wait until first element in table will appear
3. Maybe during search some attribute changes (e.g. in input), or it's become disabled, or btn becomes disabled
4. Maybe during search you can get requests which server send, and verify it's content,

I don't know what else... i need to see it. Anyway, try to find some place that changes during search (or after search), it will help you

Comment: Hmm very good suggestion I'm going to try nr 1. Numm 2 won't work since there could be a lot of results and not a specific one would be shown at the first page. I'll try #1 out thx

Comment: using the wait on the ' processing ' is good, when it's hidden again it stops/request is done thanks ;D you should totally look at my unanswered questions XD